# Using JavaScript Fetch() and formData() To Update A Database

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, fetch, form-data

I have some javascript `fetch()` on a project and, although it works, the issue I have is, (although I understand the basics of `fetch` and `formData`), the piece of code seems overly complicated for what it is doing, and I don't understand how it is working?

I have some PHP that when a download button is clicked it updates a 'downloads' count in a MySQL database. I've included the PHP at the end, but it isn't really relevant to the issue.

What I don't understand is, if the form button is assigned to a `downloadButton` variable, why the code is written how it is, particularly on the `click` event listener?

It would be amazing if someone could explain this to me and possibly show a better way of doing it using the `downloadButton` variable?

I've added code comments on the parts I don't understand.

Also please feel free to explain this as if you are talking to an idiot - I am new to JavaScript/software development.

**Note:** Using JSON / URL endpoints is not an option.

**JavaScript**

```
let forms = document.querySelectorAll('.download-form-js'),
    downloadButton = document.querySelectorAll('.dl-button')

// URL details
let myURL = new URL(window.location.href), // get URL
pagePath = myURL.pathname // add pathname to get full URL

if (forms) {
        forms.forEach(item => {
            
            // Why is it done like this when a variable is assigned to the download button above?
            item.querySelectorAll('[type="submit"], button').forEach( button => {
                button.addEventListener("click", e => item._button = button); //store this button in the form element?
            })

            // The 'btn' parameter in this function isn't used ?
            item.addEventListener("submit", function(evt, btn) {

                evt.preventDefault();

                const formData = new FormData(this);

                // Can the parameters inside the '.set()' function not be done with the 'downloadButton' variable?
                if (this._button) // submitted by a button?
                {
                    formData.set(this._button.name, this._button.value);
                    delete this._button; // have no idea why this is even used?
                }

            fetch (pagePath, {
                method: 'post',
                body: formData
            }).then(function(response){
                return response.text();
            // }).then(function(data){
            //     console.log(data);
            }).catch(function (error){
                console.error(error);
            })

        })

    })

} // end of if (forms)
```

**HTML**
This form appears at least twice on any page.

```
<section>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
    </div>
    <form class="download-form-js" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div class="dl-button-wrapper">
                <label for="download-button">Download</label>
                <button id="download-button" type="submit" name="download" title="Download" value="12" class="dl-button"></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="image-id" value="12">
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

**PHP (not really relevant, but thought I'd include it)**

Below is the PHP function that is used to update the downloads count but isn't really relevant to the above problem.

```
function downloadCounter($connection, $imageID) {
    if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
         // value from hidden form element
         $imageID = $_POST['image-id'];

         try {
              $sql = "UPDATE lj_imageposts SET downloads = downloads +1 WHERE image_id = :image_id";
              $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

              $stmt->execute([
                   ':image_id' => $imageID
              ]);

         } catch (PDOException $e) {
              echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed quite weird, but it seems somehow related to the way the form is implemented, as the values `_button.name` and `_button.value` are used to populate the formData (also multiple submit buttons seems to be expected...), so it could be useful to see the HTML. But anyway I think this implementation is rather twisted...

Comment: @Peterrabbit it is used on two pages of the site. On one of the those pages there are two options to download the image (each having their own submit button with the same `.dl-button` class that is referenced with the `downloadButton` variable). That side of I get, in terms of the forEach etc, I just can't seem to get it to work when using the `downloadButton` variable. I also think the `btn` parameter is just something that doesn't need to be there so I might remove that.

Comment: In the HTML you added, there is only one submit "download" button, and it doesn't have a `value` attribute. Is this representative of the reality ? It quite doesn't stick with the JS code which processes a button collection for each form.

Comment: Hi @Peterrabbit - no, sorry I have tweaked the HTML and put a small note above it. it does have a value attribute and I've noted it appears at least twice on the pages where it used. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a high level, I see this code as trying to implement the following behavior (albeit in a very strange way)

1. Automatically add form handlers to every `<form>` that has class `.download-form-js`
2. Add information to the POST request about which button actually submitted the form.

Most of your questions relate to the odd way that it tries to accomplish goal #2. Peterrabbit did a good job going through these one-by-one, so I won't do that again. Fortunately, there's a much simpler way of doing this - by leveraging the `submitter` property of the `FormEvent` (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter)). Check out the refactored code below, which is also in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-javascript-fetch-979cm4?file=/src/refactored.js:75-643):

```
const forms = document.querySelectorAll(".download-form-js");
forms.forEach((form) => {
  form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(this);

    // see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter
    if (e.submitter) {
      formData.set(e.submitter.name, e.submitter.value);
    }

    fetch(pagePath, {
      method: "post",
      body: formData
    })
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch((e) => console.error(e));
  });
});
```

That basically dispenses with the need to register event handlers on every button in the form (whose only purpose was to, when clicked, register themselves on the form object so the form "submit" event could figure which button was clicked, and add to the POST request).

In the linked [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-javascript-fetch-979cm4?file=/index.html:1493-1583) I have this refactored implementation running side-by-side with your original implementation, as well as a comparison with what would happen if you got rid of javascript altogether and just used a simple `<form action="FORM_HANLDER_URL" method="post">`. I also tried to respond to your comments inline in the [`src/original.js`](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-javascript-fetch-979cm4?file=/src/original.js) file.

Comment: Thanks Andrew - the `e.submitter` property was the holy grail I was looking for.

Comment: Hi Andrew - I have a side-effect happening that involves this form on this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898367/use-javascript-fetch-and-formdata-on-one-specific-button-in-a-form  I don't know if you can see a way to fix what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

```js
forms.forEach(item => {
    // Why is it done like this when a variable is assigned to the download button above?
    item.querySelectorAll('[type="submit"], button').forEach(button => {
```

Because the variable `downloadButton` is a collection of ALL download buttons in the page, but `item.querySelectorAll('[type="submit"], button')` takes only the buttons nested inside the form being iterated.

```js
      button.addEventListener("click", e => item._button = button); //store this button in the form element?
    })
```

The reference of the button HtmlElement is stored as an attribute of the form HtmlElement.

```js
    // The 'btn' parameter in this function isn't used ?
    item.addEventListener("submit", function(evt, btn) {
```

That `btn` argument can't be used, as said in this docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback
An eventListener callback only support the `event` as argument. So this `btn` is just `undefined` in all cases.

```js
      // Can the parameters inside the '.set()' function not be done with the 'downloadButton' variable?
      if (this._button) // submitted by a button?
      {
        formData.set(this._button.name, this._button.value);
        delete this._button; // have no idea why this is even used?
      }
```

Same answer than above, if the variable `downloadButtons` is used, the button won't be related to the form. (it actually would be possible but with more operations to identify the parent form)

If I got the logic well, the fact that a `_button` attribute is present means that a submit button have been clicked, and that same button is referenced in that attribute `_button`. So we can get the values we want with its `name` and `value`.

Then the `_button` attribute is deleted because if another button is clicked inside the same form it will replace this one (even if in that precise case it's useless to delete the attribute, it could just be reassigned). But maybe the form can also be submitted without any of those buttons being clicked (?), it would explain the `if this._button`...

Again I think this implementation is quite twisted.
But I don't know all details of this implementation so I don't know if I can propose a more relevant way to do it..

Comment: Thanks Peter. I've added a simplified version of the HTML form that is present in multiple instances on each page (on one page because there are multiple images, and on the other page because there are two places on the page you can download the image. I don't know if this makes it easier to assign/use the `downloadButton` variable and/or to do it in a more logical way.