# Use JavaScript Fetch and FormData On One Specific Button In A Form

Tags: javascript, forms, events, dom-events, fetch-api

I have a form that submits image filenames and other information via PHP to a MySQL database which all works OK on the backend. On the frontend I'm using the JavaScript `fetch()` API to ensure when certain functionality is undertaken there is no hard refresh of the page (specifically if an image is deleted prior to form submission).

The JavaScript below prevents the page doing a hard refresh when an image component is deleted using the `.remove-image` button, and it also then removes the HTML of the image component as desired. There is however a side-effect to this code when the main form submission happens:

**Problem**

When the main form submission happens via the `.upload-details` button this too is being affected by the `fetch()` code. I only want the fetch code to fire when the delete button is clicked not when the main submission button is clicked. I thought I could achieve this by wrapping the `if (fetchForms) {}`  code in a click event listener on the `.remove-image` button, but this doesn't work either (I've included this code below). It still seems to fire the `e.submitter.closest('.upload-details-component').remove()` line of code?

**Note:** This problem only happens after the `.remove-image` button has been clicked. If the `.remove-image` button is never clicked the main `.upload-details` button works as it should.

The error message I get is 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'remove') at app.js:234:77' which relates to this line of code `e.submitter.closest('.upload-details-component').remove()`

**My Question**

How do I get it so the `fetch()` code only works when the delete `.remove-image` button is clicked and not when the main `.upload-details` button is clicked, under all circumstances?

When I do a hard page refresh after the main `.upload-details-component` button has been pressed, although it had thrown an error in the console, the form submission has taken place. So I guess I need a way of turning the fetch() off when this other button is clicked?

**JavaScript**

```
let fetchForms = document.querySelectorAll('.fetch-form-js'),
removeImageButton = document.querySelectorAll('.remove-image')

// URL details
var myURL = new URL(window.location.href),
pagePath = myURL.pathname


removeImageButton.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {

        if (fetchForms) {
            fetchForms.forEach((item) => {
                item.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    
                    const formData = new FormData(this);

                    if (e.submitter) {
                        formData.set(e.submitter.name, e.submitter.value);
                    }

                    fetch(pagePath, {
                        method: "post",
                        body: formData
                    })
                    .then(function(response){
                        // only remove component if the 'remove-image' button is clicked
                        e.submitter.closest('.upload-details-component').remove()
                        
                        return response.text();
                    // }).then(function(data){
                    //     console.log(data);
                    }).catch(function (error){
                        console.error(error);
                    })

                })

            });

        } // end of if (forms)

    }) // 'remove' button clickEvent
}) // removeImageButton forEach
```

**HTML**

**Note:** The image component is outputted with a `while` loop because there will almost always be more than one of them. I've only shown one component below for simplicity.

```
<form class="fetch-form-js" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <!-- IMAGE DETAILS COMPONENT. THESE COMPONENTS ARE OUTPUTTED WITH A WHILE LOOP --> 
    
    <div class="upload-details-component">                
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="image-title">Image Title</label>
            <input id="title-title>" class="input-title" type="text" name="image-title[]">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="tags">Comma Separated Image Tags</label>
            <textarea id="tags" class="text-area" type="text" name="image-tags[]"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <!-- DELETE BUTTON -->
            <button name="upload-details-delete" value="12" class="remove-image">DELETE</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="image-id[]" value="12">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- IMAGE DETAILS COMPONENT - END -->

    <div class="form-row upload-details-submit-row">
        <button id="upload-submit" class="upload-details" type="submit" name="upload-submit">COMPLETE UPLOADS</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Your code attaches a handler for the form's submit event. It sounds like you only want to handle the delete button's click event. I don't understand why you'd try tyo delete something with a button press, yet wait to remove the element until the form is submitted. Perhaps you should say the logic out-loud to yourself see where it fails.

Comment: @enhzflep - the images/components are outputted from a database, the code above is the second stage of the process where the user adds image details. I need to communicate with the database to delete the image, I'm not just deleting an HTML component.

Comment: ahh, sorry missed that detail in your initial post. Okay, so why not just send an ajax request whenever they press the remove button? Why not tell the backend right then, that the image is superfluous to user requirements? Also, do you mean you're storing the filenames in the database, or are you storing the actual files themselves? Unless I'm mistaken &/or migration is something you need to do often, you get *much better* performance and utilization of resources if you let the filesystem store the file and simply chuck metadata (orig name, blah, blah) into the database.

Comment: @enhzflep - yes, sorry the image filenames are stored in the database. The images are in folders. I thought wrapping the fetch() inside the delete button click event would do that, but it still threw an error. Let me add that code and comment it out so people can uncomment it to see what happens.

Comment: @enhzflep I've edited the question and added the click event code to the question that I originally tried: i.e having the code only fire when the remove button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I understand your high-level goals to be:

1. When any `.remove-image` button is clicked, handle it by cancelling the default browser behavior (i.e. post + page redirect), and instead do a `fetch` call to your server endpoint, and, if successful, remove the parts of the form corresponding to the image that was deleted.
2. Keep the `upload-submit` behavior as the default (i.e. post + page redirect)

Let me first walk through how your code is currently working and why you're seeing the current behavior:

1. When the page loads, you're registering a "click" handler on all `.remove-image` buttons on the page:

   ```
   let removeImageButton = document.querySelectorAll(".remove-image");
   removeImageButton.forEach((button) => {
      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // ...
      })
   })
   ```
2. Whenever any `.remove-image` button is clicked, it will register a form `submit` handler on *all* `.fetch-form-js` forms that were found when the page loaded. This handler  will execute when *any* `<button type="submit">` element in the form is clicked (including the `upload-submit` button). The handler cancels the default browser redirect behavior, manually executes a `fetch` request, and then tries to `remove` the `.upload-details-component` element that is the closest parent of whatever button was pressed to submit the form:

   ```
   // When the page loads..
   let fetchForms = document.querySelectorAll(".fetch-form-js")

   // After any .remove-button is clicked...
   fetchForms.forEach((item) => {
      // ...register this handler on all .fetch-form-js forms.
      item.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
          // When a .fetch-form-js is submitted (including by pressing and upload-submit button...

          // ...prevent browser redirect...
          e.preventDefault() 

          // ...

          // ...execute a fetch request...
          fetch(/* ... */)
              // ... and, if successful, hide the .upload-details-component element that is
              // the closest parent of whatever button was clicked to submit the form.
              .then( function(response) {

                  e.submitter.closest(".upload-details-component").remove()
                  // ...
              })
          // ...
      })
   })
   ```

The main problem here is that the `item.addEventListener("submit")` handler will execute on *all* submit buttons, including the `upload-submit` button (which you want to keep with the default behavior). That's exactly what you *don't* want.

A secondary problem is that *when* it executes because an `upload-submit` button is clicked, `e.submitter.closest(".upload-details-component")` will be `null` (because there is no `.upload-details-component` that is a parent of `upload-submit`)

Here's a way to refactor this to avoid both problems:

```
const fetchForms = document.querySelectorAll(".fetch-form-js");

// Simplify things by only registering "submit" events.
fetchForms.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    if (
      e.submitter &&
      // This will be "true" if the "remove-image" button is clicked to submit the form,
      // and false if the ".upload-submit" button is clicked to submit the form.
      // This way, you'll keep browser default behavior for the ".upload-submit" button 100% of the time.
      e.submitter.classList.contains("remove-image")
    ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const formData = new FormData(this);
      formData.set(e.submitter.name, e.submitter.value);
      fetch(pagePath, {
        method: "post",
        body: formData
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          e.submitter.closest(".upload-details-component").remove();
          return response.text();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  });
});
```

See [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-javascript-fetch-side-effect-zipxlt?file=/src/refactored.js) for a working example and a side-by-side comparison with your original code.

Comment: Thanks Andrews that's great. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: hi @andrewStegmaier - I have another problem which is kind of related to this that I can't seem to fix which I've put a bounty on. Any wisdom much appreciated as ever - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72120078/using-a-fetch-get-request-after-a-fetch-post-request-has-been-submitted-to-o